# Keeping original colors

Tags: opengl, textures, glut, alpha, blending

I'm trying to place a texture (with alpha) on another texture in *OpenGL*. I do it without any problems, but it's not as I wanted: my *nearest image*'s color is strongly affected by *background image* (furthest texture) resulting in appearing orange in spite of red.

Anyone knows a way of blending (or getting rid of alpha) that will resolve this issue?

Blending initialization:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
```

Drawing scene:

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glLoadIdentity();

//furthest image (background)
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(0, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(500, 0);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(500, 500);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(0, 500);
glEnd();

//nearest image (appears orange, should be red) 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 0); glVertex2f(100, 100);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 0); glVertex2f(300, 100);
    glTexCoord2f(1, 1); glVertex2f(300, 300);
    glTexCoord2f(0, 1); glVertex2f(100, 300);
glEnd();

glutSwapBuffers();
```

EDIT.
Here's an image depicting how it looks:
[image: issue]

Here's an image of how it should look:
[image: target]

Comment: I can't see what colours you're mixing, what you want to achieve and what you achieve actually. If the nearest image is transparent, why wouldn't it be affected by its background? What's wrong with orange?

Comment: @Kos Well, I've got a background which is a green grass and I've got a red texture which has spots where alpha is used. In those places I want to have mentioned background (grass). It's like 2D game, player walking on a surface. Instead my background color influences "player's" thus my red texture turns into orange (red + green).

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is 'alpha testing', not blending. See

```
glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)
glAlphaFunc()
```

If you want to leave blending enabled, you should use

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

This will only use the source color in places where the source alpha is 1. Currently your function adds the source color to the background color.

If you don't want any mixing of colors, then using alpha test is the better way to go, as it uses less resources then blending.

Comment: This doesn't work either. It creates black surface around my texture (around that R letter).

Comment: Sounds to me like your image's alpha channel is missing or broken. @Robin92

Comment: You were right! Resaving my texture as PNG (was BMP) resolved an issue. Thanks :) @Tim

Answer (score 2):

This blend func

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
```

is the cause of your problems. The `GL_ONE` for destination means, that whatever is present already in the framebuffer will be added to the incoming colour regardles of the alpha value.

In your case your red texture gets added with the greenish background. And since *red + greenish = orange* this is what you get.

What you want is mask the previous content in the destination framebuffer with your alpha channel, which is done using

```
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Also remember that OpenGL state is meant to be set and reset on demand, so when drawing other textures then you might need other setting for blending and blend func.

Answer (score 0):

With help of you all, I managed to resolve the issue by:

- resaving my texture as PNG (in spite of BMP)
- changing blending function to `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`

Thanks to all contributtors :)